# How to avoid rebuild ipa file in enterprise distribution due to expired profiles

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, iphone-developer-program

HI i developed 7 apps for enterprise distribution.These apps users cannot see in App Store and will be shared internal to enterprise. Now provisioning profile which i used is expired.I regenerate profile in developer.apple.com now its validate is increased to one more year.But my question is if i want those apps should work then I have to rebuild ipa files or is there any other way which i can avoid to recreate builds.

Please help me this will help me a lot if i can avoid rebuild creation i can avoid testing all these 7 apps so I can save so much time.Please help me thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply re-sign the existing apps so that you won't have to re-test.  This is especially important if you've migrated to a newer version of Xcode and some older projects may require changes to work in the newer version.

For details of how exactly to re-sign the ipa, see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25656455/3708242

For our internal apps using our enterprise distribution profile, we have put in self-update logic that allows us to push updates so that the users won't end up with an app that won't launch due to an expired provisioning profile or certificate. You might consider adding a similar mechanism so your users don't have to know to go and get the latest builds with the new provisioning profiles.  That, combined with a yearly calendar reminder, should help you keep up with things.

Comment: Can you share the self-update logic? any link please?

Comment: Can't share the code, but the basic approach was to have a web-accessible file containing the lowest supported version, along with a url to the current version's plist.  Then, in the app delegate's applicationDidBecomeActive method, we download the file that has the version and url, and if the current version of the app is lower than the version in the file, we prompt the user and then install the newer version using  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:]].  Hope this helps get you started.

Comment: sounds very interesting, but openURL with a local file? 

Comment: No, the data file that specifies what current version the app should be needs to be accessible on a web server that the devices can communicate with.  Also, the .ipa file for the latest build also needs to be web accessible.  There is no local storage for a .ipa file on iOS that you can install from.  Put the version.dat and the latest-version.ipa on an internal web server and you should be good to go.